# Adding an index to an existing column

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a datatable that I load into from DB:

```
class DoQuery
{
    public static DataTable DoReadQuery(string DoSqlQuery)
    {
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        Helper objAccessToDb = new Helper();
        using (var connection = new MySqlConnection(objAccessToDb.DbAccess))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (var command = new MySqlCommand(DoSqlQuery, connection))
            {
                using (MySqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    dt.Load(dr);
                }
            }
            connection.Close();
        }
        return (dt);
    }
}
```

it works well, but I need the same index in my datatable as I have on my DB.
How can I  get the same index from my DB into my DataTable without adding new specfic column to DB? Is there a way to do so or it can be done in alternative ways?
Please provide any guidance.

Comment: What does `without adding an additional line` mean? Without an additional line of code?

Comment: `without adding an additional line`  Why would you have this as a requirement?

Comment: Queries don't return the schema of the underlying table(s). They can't - what would the server return for something that came from UNIONs or aggregates? Or joins between multiple tables? You'll have to set the `PrimaryKey` explicitly.

Comment: Use parameters to avoid sql injection and formatting errors.  Your DoReadQuery function isn't built to do this.

Comment: @RandRandom, ->Amy - sorry, meant to say without adding an additional column.

->LarsTech - Thanks and I am aware of this. This is an internal code, no outside influence.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - ok and how would you go to do this, please?

Comment: Why do you think "I need the same index in my datatable"? AFAIK the DataTable class doesn't have an index. Why do you think it needs one? Are you having performance issues in your code?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, yes, I have performance issue and I would like to use this or find() - maybe I go around this the wrong way. 
My intention is to compare to datatables and see if something has changed. So I am crawling through two foreachs which takes quite a lot of time - we are talking about 30 seconds.

Comment: Are both datatables loading from the same DB? Just do it in the DB!

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid no. the "old" is a copy of the same table, after a cycle.

Comment: What does "after a cycle" mean? What is the objective of what you are doing? comparing data in the same table after a process has been applied to it? It's entirely likely this can be done in the database but it's highly unlikely that sufficient info will be applied to resolve this.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, first thanks for coming back.

I have a table with 10s of thousands of rows and some are changing every second. I want to catch them as fast as I can and do something with the changed rows.

Comment: What is the "something" that you are doing with it? Does this "something" end up in the same database? I can't help here any further really. thirteen comments later and we're still in the dark.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, well the thread 'evolved' as my question was not answered and it went a different path.

Something will be send out over the network - so basically the difference/changed rows, will be send away.

Comment: In answer to "How can I get the same index from my DB into my DataTable", as far as understand it, you cannot index a .Net datatable like a database table.

Answer (score 0):

The consensus here is that this is not possible.